# How can I combine the common behavior behind hover events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

When I wrote a hover event with jquery, there was a common behavior I wanted to do with both mouseenter and mouseleave.

```
$foo.hover(
  function () {
    common_before_process();
    // ...
    common_after_process();
  },
  function () {
    common_before_process();
    // ...
    common_after_process();
  }
);
```

I have extracted the processing as a function here, but I think that it will be easier to read if these two processes are completely removed from the event handler. So the question is, is there a way to concisely describe the common processes extracted by the above functions?

For example, what I want is the following behavior (an example only):

```
$foo.hoverAfter(common_after_process);
$foo.hoverBefore(common_before_process);

$foo.hover(
  function () {
    // ...
  },
  function () {
    // ...
  }
);
```

Comment: You might also be interested in the [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) and [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event) events.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing a callback to a common function.  Something like:

```
function toggleHover (callback) {
  common_before_process();
  callback();
  common_after_process();
}

function methodForHoverOn () {}
function methodForHoverOff () {}

$foo.hover(
  function () {
    toggleHover(methodForHoverOn);
  },
  function () {
    toggleHover(methodForHoverOff);
  }
);
```

The one method executes the common logic, and also executes the closure passed in, which is variable to whatever you need.